# À la recherche d'une expression pour « bring to the table »

Tags: vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

Bonjour tout le monde,

Je suis à la rechercher d'une expression qui veut dire à peu près « bring [qch] to the table » d'une façon figurative.

Par exemple, en anglais, on peut dire

> Yes she's a very good engineer, but what she really brings to the table is an extraordinary ability to communicate complex ideas simply.

et donc j'aimerais trouver quelque chose qui peut marcher en français aussi:

> Oui, c'est une ingénieure très douée, mais ce qu'elle [??] est une capacité extraordinaire à communiquer des idées complexes avec simplicité.

Je peux bien sûr faire usage de « ce qu'elle a comme atout est », « ce dont elle dispose en tant que plus grande force », etc., mais je les trouve un peu lourds et donc je me demande s'il n'y a pas quelque chose de plus idiomatique.

Comment: « elle est une < métier, profession, … > »n'est pas idiomatique; à moins que vous vouliez introduire un nouvel usage (copié sur l'anglais), il faut dire « c'est une … ». Aussi, après « soit » il faut une ponctuation ( virgule ou point d'exclamation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'expression signifierait « to contribute (something) to a group effort » ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bring_to_the_table)). Ça peut sembler banal comme c'est une traduction directe du verbe, mais dans le contexte de la phrase en question je dirais simplement « apporter » dans le sens de *fournir* ([Ac.9](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9A2238), [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/apporter), [Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/apporter#cac2f64438817e0a)). La question devient quel complément ajouter (*to a group effort* i.e. le « *to the table* »).

Peut-être que ce n'est pas vraiment requis et qu'on peut ajouter au besoin [*vraiment*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vraiment) en valeur intensive, si on veut contraster avec la simple qualité d'être très qualifié(e). Ou on pourrait ajouter « à/dans une/l'équipe » si c'est le cas, selon qu'on parle de ce qu'elle pourrait faire (si elle était embauchée ; *une*) ou de ce qu'elle fait déjà (si on commente son travail actuel ; *l'*) ; il semble qu'on puisse employer les prépositions *à* ou *dans* pour le complément indirect (Ac.9).

> ...mais ce qu'elle **apporte** (vraiment) (à/dans une/l'équipe) est une
> capacité extraordinaire de communiquer des idées complexes avec
> simplicité.

Je pense qu'il faut adapter le « to the table » à chaque situation<sup>1</sup> ou carrément omettre le complément.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Ce n'est pas la question mais dans l'exemple sur *Wiktionary* on a un défi : « I don’t have time for a man unless he can bring something big to the table, like a huge amount of money. ». Je pense que c'est « quelque chose de substantiel *dans la/ma vie* »...</sub>

Comment: Je suis pas certain d'avoir compris le « figuratif » dans la question. Néanmoins. L'[_épaule qu'elle met à la roue_](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/%C3%A9paule#bbed) hahahaha.

Answer (score 1):

En tant que forme de base il existe le verbe « apporter ». C'est une terme d'application plus vaste, comme le sujet peut être autre chose qu'une personne ou un groupe.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/apporter)) **B.** − [L'obj. désigne une valeur concr. ou abstr. dont la pers. ou l'obj. destinataire doit ressentir l'effet le plus souvent heureux]
>
> **1.** [Le suj. désigne une pers.; le destinataire ou bénéficiaire explicite ou implicite désigne une pers. ou une entité étroitement liée à la pers.] Mettre à la disposition, au service de quelqu'un (ou d'un groupe).
>
> **b)** En gén. :
> • C'est égal, j'ai du cœur et de la conviction, je sais sur quel immense appui, invisible encore, je me soutiens, et je vais dans quelques jours les déchaîner davantage quand je parlerai sur la réforme électorale que j'admets, et sur l'instruction secondaire, où je leur apporterai des idées hardies qui les feront tous cabrer. Lamartine, Correspondance,1834, p. 8.
>
> • Que j'aime cette première parole du père Lacordaire à son auditoire de Nancy : « Mes frères, je vous apporte le bonheur! » La chasse de Stendhal vieillissant l'éloignait chaque jour davantage de l'objet même de sa recherche. Mauriac, Journal 3,1940, p. 328.

([réf. 1996](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Sciences_et_savoirs_aux_XVIe_et_XVIIe_si/nZjqs55QO2cC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22qu%27elle+apporte+c%27est%22&pg=PA12&printsec=frontcover)) Car une découverte est reconnue en raison de ce qu'elle apporte , c'est à dire à la fois de ce qu'elle permet de comprendre et de ce qu'elle permet de découvrir : dans les deux cas , il faut du temps pour la confirmer , et plus encore ...

([réf. 2019](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Jeanne_d_Arc_M%C3%A9dium/Xj6dDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22qu%27elle+apporte+c%27est%22&pg=PA49&printsec=frontcover)) Et voyez quel mystère admirable ! C'est une enfant qui vient tirer la France de l'abîme. Qu'apporte-t-elle donc avec elle ? Est-ce un secours militaire ? Une armée ? Non, rien de tout cela. Ce qu'elle apporte, c'est la foi en soi-même, ...