# La locution « mettre la main à la pâte » autorise-t-elle un complément (de manière/nature) ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, locutions, compléments

La locution verbale « [mettre la main à la pâte](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mettre_la_main_%C3%A0_la_p%C3%A2te) » (« participer à la tâche, au travail qu’il y a à faire... », Wiktionnaire) conjuguée permet-elle un complément introduit ou induit par une préposition ou un adverbe (*comment, en, par* etc.) pour [expliquer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52118/%C3%80-la-recherche-dune-expression-pour-bring-to-the-table#comment108169_52121) ce dont il est question ?

Comment: En général oui : *mettre la main à la pâte avec ardeur*. Mais la question est floue, il faudrait des exemples précis.

Comment: @guillaume31 J'avais rédigé la question autrement mais elle était trop bizarre à mon goût. C'est le lien sous « expliquer » qui explique (l'épaule qu'elle met à la roue + est). Je voulais savoir si on peut compléter ou expliciter la « main ».... _elle met la main à la pâte par sa capacité à communiquer des idées complexes_. Je vais y réfléchir, peut-être poser une autre question...

Comment: *elle met la main à la pâte par sa capacité à communiquer des idées complexes* : pour le coup, ça ne me parait pas être un exemple sémantiquement satisfaisant (d'où l'intérêt d'étayer la question avec des éléments de contexte). "Mettre la main à la pâte" implique plutôt une action physique, concrète et une "capacité à ..." n'explique pas en quoi elle s'y prend concrètement pour aider. Le complément parait trop éloigné de l'expression pour la compléter de manière compréhensible. "Avec" au lieu de "par" est sans doute un peu plus approprié.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il n'y a aucune règle qui l'interdit et je pense que l'expression restera compréhensible si on la modifie un peu.

Par exemple :

J'ai mis la main à la pâte pour accélérer la production.

Il met toujours la main à la pâte en chantant.

Il met doucement la main à la pâte par peur de se fatiguer.

Comment: Merci, dirais-tu que dans ton exemple avec _en chantant_, c'est surtout la simultanéité de l'action et de chanter plus que comment la main est mise à la pâte pour ainsi dire ? Dans le sens où l'action de chanter ne donne pas de détail sur l'action qui constitue la tâche.

Comment: Pour moi, "mettre la main à la pâte" signifie s'impliquer dans un travail, et souvent il s'agit d'un travail plutôt collégial. Le "en chantant" apporterait ici une notion de bonne humeur pour l'accomplissement de la tâche, pas le fait de chanter comme activité principale.